# C89 Deleting Linked Lists

Tags: linked-list, c89

I am trying to write a program that imports data from a excel file and stores names in a linked list. The first column contains a command {add, remove, flush} and the second column contains a name if the if the command is add.

It adds names to the end of the list, removes names from the front, and when it flushes, it deletes the entire list from memory. Add detects if the name is already included (not written in yet) flush and remove also detect if the the queue is empty.

example file:

```
add      dave

add      mike

remove 

add      paul

flush

add      steve
```

example output:

```
add:     dave

add:     dave, mike

remove:  mike

 flushing queue

add:      steve
```

My problem is that my flush command is not deleting the list properly. The code must be c89 compliant. Thank you for any help you can give.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
struct node* next;
char name[50];
};

struct node* addNode(char *word);
void freeNodes(struct node* head);
void removeNode (struct node* head);

int main(void)
{
struct node* head = NULL, *tail, *temp;
char buffer[50];
int i;
char *word = " ";
char *del = " ,\n";
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("queue-data.csv", "r");

while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL )
{
    word = strtok(buffer, del);

    /********     ADD      *********/

    if( strcmp(word,"add") == 0)
    {
        word = strtok(NULL, del);
        temp = addNode(word);
        if(head == NULL)
            head = temp;
        else
            tail->next = temp;

        tail = temp;
        temp = head;

        printf("   add:");
        printf(" %s", temp->name);
        temp = temp->next;

        while(temp != NULL) 
        {
            printf(", %s", temp->name);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /********     REMOVE      *********/

    else if( strcmp(word,"remove") == 0)
    {
        printf("remove:");
        if (head == NULL)
            printf(" queue is empty");
        else
        {
            removeNode(head);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    /********     FLUSH      *********/


    else if( strcmp(word,"flush") == 0)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
            printf(" flush: queue is empty");
        else
            freeNodes( head );
        printf("\n");
    }

}
freeNodes( head );
}


struct node* addNode(char *word)
{
struct node* temp = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
strcpy(temp->name, word);
temp->next = NULL;

return temp;
}

void freeNodes(struct node* head)
{
struct node* temp;

printf(" flushing queue");
while(head != NULL)
{
    temp = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = temp;
}
}

void removeNode (struct node* head)
{
struct node* temp;

temp = head->next;
free(head);
head = temp;
printf(" %s", temp->name);
temp = temp->next;
while(temp != NULL) 
{
    printf(", %s", temp->name);
    temp = temp->next;
}
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: C is the best possible language for performance and linked lists are the worst possible data structure for performance because of cache locality.  Why would you want to use a language that is hard to use and then intentionally defeat its primary use case?  IF you don't care about performance use Excel's VBA.

Comment: Can you please define "not deleting the list properly" ?  Does the program just exit without deleting anything or does it delete some of it or does it just crash?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `removeNode()` function.
It changes address of the pointer head - what is locally in `removeNode()`- and free memory of node it pointer before, while pointer head in main function not change. So when you call `removeNode(head)`, pointer head in main still point to memory where be freed in `removeNode()` function, so it went wrong commands after.
These are some solution:

- define pointer head to be global variable
- function removeNode() should return the head pointer after changed. like this: 
   `struct node* removeNode(struct node* head){}`

Tell me if it helps.